# Adding text to Settings Saved in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, settings

I am building a custom plugin in wordpress with a settings page. 
Right now everything works as expected however I want to add more functionality.

In this case when you save the settings the page reloads with a message in the top which says Settings saved. I will like to add a line of code in that message box.

Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the *[admin_notices](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices)* action hook, as well as *[settings_errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/settings_errors)*, depending on what information you're trying to output. You'll need to set the errors using *[add_settings_error](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_error)*, which will let you specify a success or error.